# Java SQL Statement for selecting record from database and using as double variable

Tags: java, sql, database, select

Java - Netbeans IDE

I have this code but the variable Priceperitem is not found, can anyone explain? or show me an easier way of selecting a record from a table in a database and setting its value as a variable?

Price P/Item is the name of column within the database table.

```
    String sql = "SELECT Price P/Item FROM tblResources";
 try {

pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

        rs = pst.executeQuery();

       while (rs.next()){

      double Priceperitem = rs.getDouble("Price P/Item");

       }

  } catch (Exception e) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Runtime Error");
    }
```

and then :

```
try {

 Total = Quantity * Priceperitem;       (This is where Priceperitem is not found.)

   btnCalculateTotal.setText("Total: £"+Total+"0");

 }catch (Exception e){

     System.out.println("Error Calculating Total");
}
```

Comment: Does that SQL execute when run directly on the database? If that really is the column name, then you'll need to escape it in your query to prevent the database misinterpreting it.

Comment: To start i would suggest modifying Database column name instead of P/Item -> Per_Item

Answer (score 1):

You have declared `Priceperitem` locally within the while loop. It is not visible outside the loop.

To fix this, move the declaration to to the outer level:

```
double Priceperitem = 0;
```

Side note: you should respect the Java naming conventions. So a better name is `pricePerItem`.